# An array of evenly spaced values when only first and last input is known

Tags: matlab

I want to create an array of N size, which has inputs evenly spaced apart. For clarification I have the first and last values of an array and want to fill the array N sized with inputs.

I have used linspace

```
 bars = 10;
 DeapA = 1;
 DeapB = 10;
 diameter_pin = (linspace(DeapA, DeapB, bars))
```

Which gives:

```
 diamter_p =

       1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
```

However is there a way of doing this by filling an array as such ?

The reason I want to do this is because in more complicated versions of the above when I used the variable in an equation the values are not being calculated correctly

Comment: It's not a full answer but try making your "array elements" a fixed width by writing a function.  You could also then try the justify characters.  In other languages a justify-right usually prints something in a fixed width as you are mentioning.  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjust.html

Comment: Please clarify what exactly is not working with `linspace`, perhaps give an example where values are not being calculated correctly.

Comment: You'll have to give an example of what you want your matrix to look like. Do you want the number sequence to repeat on each line? Do you want the numbers to wrap around each line? Do you want each line to increase both in rows and columns?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do, so here are a few answers

### Wrapping numbers around

```
bars = 10;
DeapA = 1;
DeapB = 10;
diameter_pin = reshape(linspace(DeapA, DeapB, bars*bars), bars, bars)
```

Gives an array where each column has equally spaced points, and the values keep increasing through the columns

```
diameter_pin =

    1.0000    1.9091    2.8182    3.7273    4.6364    5.5455    6.4545    7.3636    8.2727    9.1818
    1.0909    2.0000    2.9091    3.8182    4.7273    5.6364    6.5455    7.4545    8.3636    9.2727
    1.1818    2.0909    3.0000    3.9091    4.8182    5.7273    6.6364    7.5455    8.4545    9.3636
    1.2727    2.1818    3.0909    4.0000    4.9091    5.8182    6.7273    7.6364    8.5455    9.4545
    1.3636    2.2727    3.1818    4.0909    5.0000    5.9091    6.8182    7.7273    8.6364    9.5455
    1.4545    2.3636    3.2727    4.1818    5.0909    6.0000    6.9091    7.8182    8.7273    9.6364
    1.5455    2.4545    3.3636    4.2727    5.1818    6.0909    7.0000    7.9091    8.8182    9.7273
    1.6364    2.5455    3.4545    4.3636    5.2727    6.1818    7.0909    8.0000    8.9091    9.8182
    1.7273    2.6364    3.5455    4.4545    5.3636    6.2727    7.1818    8.0909    9.0000    9.9091
    1.8182    2.7273    3.6364    4.5455    5.4545    6.3636    7.2727    8.1818    9.0909   10.0000
```

You can take the transpose of this matrix if you want the rows to be increasing instead.

### Repeating Rows/columns

Here, each row is the same

```
>> nRows = 5;
>> nCols = 10;
>> a = 1;
>> b = 10;
>> diameter_pin = repmat(linspace(a, b, nCols), nRows, 1)

diameter_pin =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
```

Here, each column is the same

```
>> nRows = 5;
>> nCols = 10;
>> a = 1;
>> b = 10;
>> diameter_pin = repmat(linspace(a, b, nRows)', 1, nCols)

diameter_pin =

    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
    3.2500    3.2500    3.2500    3.2500    3.2500    3.2500    3.2500    3.2500    3.2500    3.2500
    5.5000    5.5000    5.5000    5.5000    5.5000    5.5000    5.5000    5.5000    5.5000    5.5000
    7.7500    7.7500    7.7500    7.7500    7.7500    7.7500    7.7500    7.7500    7.7500    7.7500
   10.0000   10.0000   10.0000   10.0000   10.0000   10.0000   10.0000   10.0000   10.0000   10.0000
```

### Equally Spaced points from top-left to bottom-right

In this matrix, each row is equally spaced with the same difference, and each column is equally spaced with the same difference. If the number of rows and columns are the same, then the entire matrix is equally spaced!

First, a rectangular matrix:

```
>> nRows = 10;
>> nCols = 5;
>> a = 1;
>> b = 10;
>> x = linspace(a, b, nCols);
>> y = linspace(a, b, nRows);
>> [xx, yy] = meshgrid(x, y);
>> zz = mean(cat(3, xx, yy), 3)

zz =

    1.0000    2.1250    3.2500    4.3750    5.5000
    1.5000    2.6250    3.7500    4.8750    6.0000
    2.0000    3.1250    4.2500    5.3750    6.5000
    2.5000    3.6250    4.7500    5.8750    7.0000
    3.0000    4.1250    5.2500    6.3750    7.5000
    3.5000    4.6250    5.7500    6.8750    8.0000
    4.0000    5.1250    6.2500    7.3750    8.5000
    4.5000    5.6250    6.7500    7.8750    9.0000
    5.0000    6.1250    7.2500    8.3750    9.5000
    5.5000    6.6250    7.7500    8.8750   10.0000
```

Now you can see the columns are equally spaced:

```
>> diff(zz)

ans =

    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000
    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000
    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000
    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000
    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000
    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000
    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000
    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000
    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000
```

And the rows are equally spaced

```
>> diff(zz')'

ans =

    1.1250    1.1250    1.1250    1.1250
    1.1250    1.1250    1.1250    1.1250
    1.1250    1.1250    1.1250    1.1250
    1.1250    1.1250    1.1250    1.1250
    1.1250    1.1250    1.1250    1.1250
    1.1250    1.1250    1.1250    1.1250
    1.1250    1.1250    1.1250    1.1250
    1.1250    1.1250    1.1250    1.1250
    1.1250    1.1250    1.1250    1.1250
    1.1250    1.1250    1.1250    1.1250
```

If you want the entire matrix to be equally spaced, then you need the same number of rows and columns. Here is the translation of your code:

```
>> bars = 10;
>> DeapA = 1;
>> DeapB = 10;
>> x = linspace(DeapA, DeapB, bars);
>> diameter_pin = nan(bars, bars, 2);
>> [diameter_pin(:, :, 1), diameter_pin(:, :, 2)] = meshgrid(x, x);
>> diameter_pin = mean(diameter_pin, 3)


diameter_pin =

    1.0000    1.5000    2.0000    2.5000    3.0000    3.5000    4.0000    4.5000    5.0000    5.5000
    1.5000    2.0000    2.5000    3.0000    3.5000    4.0000    4.5000    5.0000    5.5000    6.0000
    2.0000    2.5000    3.0000    3.5000    4.0000    4.5000    5.0000    5.5000    6.0000    6.5000
    2.5000    3.0000    3.5000    4.0000    4.5000    5.0000    5.5000    6.0000    6.5000    7.0000
    3.0000    3.5000    4.0000    4.5000    5.0000    5.5000    6.0000    6.5000    7.0000    7.5000
    3.5000    4.0000    4.5000    5.0000    5.5000    6.0000    6.5000    7.0000    7.5000    8.0000
    4.0000    4.5000    5.0000    5.5000    6.0000    6.5000    7.0000    7.5000    8.0000    8.5000
    4.5000    5.0000    5.5000    6.0000    6.5000    7.0000    7.5000    8.0000    8.5000    9.0000
    5.0000    5.5000    6.0000    6.5000    7.0000    7.5000    8.0000    8.5000    9.0000    9.5000
    5.5000    6.0000    6.5000    7.0000    7.5000    8.0000    8.5000    9.0000    9.5000   10.0000
```

This matrix is equally spaced along each dimension.

---

Well that's all I could think of. I encourage you to check out the MATLAB help documentation for all the functions I called.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using `linspace` (though I don't see why), you could use:

```
diameter_pin = DeapA : (DeapB-DeapA)/(bars-1) : DeapB;
```

Comment: This will often give different results from `linspace`. `linspace` and colon use different algorithms to space out the intermediate numbers.

Comment: @SamRoberts Really? Do you mean like finite-precision induced differences, or more  serious differences? Can you give an example?

Comment: Well, the numerical differences are typically extremely small, but the point (which is maybe only academic for most people) is that `colon` and `linspace` have slightly different purposes and use different algorithms. `colon` ensures that its output is symmetrical, and works essentially by adding up increments to the midpoint, and subtracting increments away from the endpoint. `linspace` tries to make sure that its output is as evenly spaced as possible, which is not quite the same. It's easy to find examples where they differ, e.g. `a = 0:0.1:1; b = linspace(0,1,11); all(a==b)` gives `0`.